# Seeking climate and related sciences textbook recommendations

Tags: climate, climate-models, data-analysis, reference-request

I will be starting a Master's program in data science soon and my eventual hope/goal is to do climate-related data science work. I did an independent study for one semester in college on the mathematics of climate and it inspired me to want to learn more and possibly pursue climate research as a career path. The two main textbooks I used for that class were [Mathematics of Climate](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611972610?mobileUi=0) (Hans Kaper and Hans Engler) and [Atmosphere, Ocean, and Climate Dynamics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0125586914) (John Marshall and R. Alan Plumb). My undergrad major was applied math, so my knowledge is limited mainly to content in those two books. In hopes of obtaining more background knowledge on environmental and climate sciences, I'm wondering if anyone can recommend textbooks that I could self-study before I start the program, so that I could potentially do a climate-related final project. I'm hoping to gain as wide a range of knowledge as I can during the next couple of months, so I welcome suggestions on anything (whether textbooks or other resources) that might be useful or just plain interesting! I will also mention that any books that include data assimilation would be superb. Thank you!

Comment: This is free to download this month: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-94-007-5757-8

Comment: It's a bit dated now... but this book gets into some real good examples about the energy consumption calculations involved with fossil and renewable energy.  http://www.gci.org.uk/Documents/Global-Warming-the-Complete-Briefing.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of books. I will refer you to one of [my previous answers](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13696/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-college-level-meteorology-textbook/13698#13698) which can apply to the meteorological aspects of climate. An additional classic for climate is [Physics of Climate by Peixoto and Oort](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883187124).

Answer (score 1):

["The Warming Papers"](https://www.wiley.com/en-gb/The+Warming+Papers%3A+The+Scientific+Foundation+for+the+Climate+Change+Forecast-p-9781405196161) edited by David Archer and Raymond Pierrehumbert is good for historical context.  It is basically a collection of classic journal papers, starting with Fourier and Tyndall, but it also covers key papers on climate modelling, ice cores and the carbon cycle etc.